# how to get openseamarks_data ( bouys,beacons,fisheries,oil rigs,harbours etc) to render in geoserver?

Tags: openstreetmap, geoserver, openseamap

I have been trying to render and display seamarks in any format in geoserver, but have not been able to get the source data to upload.I have browsed into websites like Mapzen,Geofabrick,Gebco ,openstreetmaps etc.The site that helped me was https://extract.bbbike.org/ , http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Seamarks/Seamark_Objects and http://www.openseamap.org/index.php?id=kartendownload&L=1,but I am unable to download source data for seamarks like bouys,beacons,ports etc to render in Geoserver.
Would anyone help me out in showing where would I get the data with these seamaks attributes in it? 
particularly around INDIAN waters (Arabian sea,Indian Ocean & Bay Of Bengal)

Answer (score 2):

Either download [raw OSM data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) and [filter it](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Filter_for_specific_tags), e.g. using osmium-tool. Or use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to download only seamarks. Either way, you have to search for the [seamark:type](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:seamark:type) tag.

Here is an [example at overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/tAR) (a frontend for Overpass API).